# sharepoint 2013 display files by user that they only created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

In a new sharepoint 2013 project that I am going to create, I need to allow users to only see the workflows, lists and documents that they create. Each person is not allowed to see each others files. I know that when in the all documents library that is being accessed by sharepoint designer 2013, that I can create a view or fillter that is:
a.'modified by' is equal to [me] and/or
b. 'created by' is equal to [me].

This way the user can only see their unique files.

Since I am new to working with sharepoint designer 2013, what I am talking about only refers to 'development' and not a production situation as far as I can tell.

Thus would you tell me and/or point me to a link (url) that would show me how to deploy/use unique views so that the user will only see the workflows, lists and documents that they created?

Answer (score 1):

For workflows and lists, this functionality is built-in. Simply go to List Settings - Advanced - Item level Permissions,  you should be able to set Read and Edit access to items that the user has created.

For documents, you can achieve this using PowerShell as below:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourSite/
$list = $web.Lists[“Your Document Library Name”]
$list.ReadSecurity = 2
$list.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

For more information, you can refer to the blog:
http://www.hersheytech.com/Blog/SharePoint/tabid/197/entryid/28/Default.aspx